# PyQt QLineEdit with history

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya, qlineedit

Do you know an easy way to make an "history" on a QLineEdit in PySide/PyQt?

Example: Whenever Enter is pressed, the typed text will be stored, and pressing the "up" or "down" arrows allows you to navigate through the history.

Thank you very much

Comment: Not a full answer, but I based a similar widget on the QtGui.QCompleter class...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Blah....

I just figured that the QComboBox does exactly what I want to do when the "setEditable" is on...

It has a completer, and an history of whatever was typed in the textfield!

Comment: how to store the history when user finishes and starts application again?